# API Gateway: Arbitrary subpath proxies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I currently have API gateway sending some proxied endpoints through a VPC Link to some microservices. As it stands, if I have an endpoint such as:

`GET /myEndpoint/subEndpoint/resource`

I have to create a resource for myEndpoint, subEndpoint, resource, and then an ANY method under `resource`. This is pretty verbose. I'd love to be able to simply proxy any requests to `/myEndpoint/*` to a particular microservice and have it handle everything else, even if it's `/myEndpoint/subpath1/subpath2/subpath3`.

Is this possible?